# Etsy OAuth Authentication (C#)

Tags: c#, api, oauth, etsy

I am working on a school project that requires the ability to send API requests to Etsy.
I have been trying for a whole week to figure out how to send an API request that requires an OAuth but to no avail.

If someone could help me create an API request in C# that requires an OAuth I would be so happy :)

Thanks So Much In Advance...
Best Regards Stephan

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Stephan! Does the API you want to request accept this type of authentication? What have you tried so far? You need to check out there for some example, try it, if it does not work, share here what is not working. Otherwise it seems you're asking here we do the complete work for you...

Answer (score 0):

I used postman to create the required API request in c#, if anyone needs any help doing so I would be happy to help.

Comment: Can help me about authorize etsy API when making a request ?

Comment: @Dakota look here to see what I did in my library, or just use the nuget version of it to get started https://github.com/Gareth064/EtsyOAuth1Authentication

Comment: @Dakota Do you still need help?

Comment: @StephanHall: Followed your steps in your library, and using the permanent token and secret returned, I am [STILL] unable to make a call to update price.  The response I get is oauth_problem=signature_invalid...   Are you able to update a price on any item in Etsy using the API?  Not tried via Postman as it's always worked from my C# app until recently, and Etsy Support are not able help.

Comment: @Dakota Are you using the new v3 Etsy API?